# Pasting selected cells within a loop statement to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows, copy-paste

I'm looking to have a loop run through a list and if any cells in Column E contain a "Y", copy the data in that row and paste it to the next empty row on the next worksheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Rec As Object
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Estimate")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("ACV & Supplement")
Set Rec = Range("E:E")

For Each cell In Rec
    If cell.Value = "Y" Then
        cell.Activate
        Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
        pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Everything works the way I expect until the `pasteSheet.Cells.....` line.

Comment: Do you get an error number and message, or does the output not look as expected?

Comment: Instead of looping, consider filtering the source by the Received column, copy and paste in one step.

Comment: I had been getting an error but when I went back to run it again, it seems to have worked as intended.  Filtering idea may work more efficiently, so may give that a shot.  Hopefully someone else will be able to use this as a reference.

Thanks again

Comment: Actually, what I would like to do is cut and paste the selected cells as opposed to copying them.  Apparently that's not as simple as changing ".Copy" to ".Cut".  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop (which can be very resource hungry) consider using an autofilter:

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet: Set copySheet = Worksheets("Estimate")
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet: Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("ACV & Supplement")

'Filter the sheet by Column E. Showing only rows where E has a "Y" value
copySheet.Range("E1:E99999").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Y", VisibleDropDown:=False

'Copy the worksheet
copySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Paste the values
pasteSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Undo the filtering
copySheet.AutoFilterMode = False

'Get rid of the marching ants
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```